# PyQt5 for web scraping, not working

Tags: python, html, pyqt5

[This is the screenshot of the error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmi5M.png)Below is my code. I am using PyQt5 with Python 3.5 to scrape a website. Kindly tell me what's wrong with my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

class Render(QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self, html):
        self.html = None
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.setHtml(html)
        while self.html is None:
            self.app.processEvents(
                QEventLoop.ExcludeUserInputEvents |
                QEventLoop.ExcludeSocketNotifiers |
                QEventLoop.WaitForMoreEvents)
        self.app.quit()

    def _callable(self, data):
        self.html = data

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.page().toHtml(self._callable)


html = 'http://www.couponraja.com/stores'

render = Render(html)
source = render.html()


soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

links = soup.select('.list-of-store li a')

for link in links:
    print (link.get('href'))
```

I am trying to access the dynamic `script` generated html components.

Comment: I can recommend use another tools - for example https://scrapy.org - it's much easier.

Comment: _...not working_. What exactly is not working? Have you done any debugging? I mean, are you able to get the HTML? Does it contain the elements it should and you are just unable to select them? Or does it give you some error?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thinkTask.py", line 33, in <module>
    source = render.html()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Well, you should've said that from the start! Try `source = render.html` instead. Without the brackets.

Comment: [warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

How to manage the above?

Comment: In continuation with above error:

2016-12-13 15:10:44.557 QtWebEngineProcess[5434:390279] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated.}
2016-12-13 15:10:44.557 QtWebEngineProcess[5434:390279] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
2016-12-13 15:10:44.557 QtWebEngineProcess[5434:390279] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!

Comment: Hmmh, it is probably not related to your actual problem, instead it seems to be a bug with qt. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56160 . I do not know if it really affects your code or not. Try `print(source)` to see if the html is correct. Cannot help more right now.